# Where should I place source code that I wish to compile?

Tags: 10.04, installation

Here's the scenario; I've downloaded a tarball. I've extracted all the source contained inside to my home folder "/home/zolomon/SourceCode". But where should I place the SourceCode directory with its content when I wish to compile it? Does it matter? 
Will it, in most cases, install and place files in the correct place automatically when I install it?

In this case I'm talking about [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/pages/download).

Comment: Do you realise that you can just install the [rubygems](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/rubygems) package?

Comment: Not if I wish to install rails 3 (but that's another matter!)?

Comment: I confirm that Rails 3 won't work with Ubuntu's current gem packages. It doesn't address your question directly but I suggest you use rvm. I just did a clean install of Ruby/Rails3 with it and it worked fine on Ubuntu 10.04. http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can place the source code anywhere.During the installation it places all the files in correct location.In your case you have your source code in **/home/zolomon/SourceCode** so you can compile it from there..Thats not a problem..

Answer (score 13):

Files under the directory `/usr/local/` are not under the control of the Debian package management system. Therefore, it is good practice to place the source code for your program in `/usr/local/src/`. For example, you might extract the files for a package named "foo.tar" into the directory `/usr/local/src/foo`. After you compile them, place the binaries in `/usr/local/bin/`, the libraries in `/usr/local/lib/`, and the configuration files in `/usr/local/etc/`.

If your programs and/or files really must be placed in some other directory, you could still store them in `/usr/local/`, and build the appropriate symbolic links from the required location to its location in `/usr/local/`, e.g., you could make the link

```
 ln -s /usr/local/bin/foo /usr/bin/foo
```

In any case, if you obtain a package whose copyright allows redistribution, you should consider making a Debian package of it, and uploading it for the Debian system. Guidelines for becoming a package developer are included in the Debian Policy manual.

Taken from: http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-compat.en.html

Comment: I never liked that option because it requires me to use root for all file creation, modification, etc.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Though, I need to read up on what files are classified as binaries, libraries and configurations in Ubuntu - I just realized I have no idea which is which!

Comment: I think that advice is misguided or outdated.  Generally, source code should just live in your home directory.  The /usr/src/ and /usr/local/src/ directories are mostly from a bygone age.

Comment: @Zolomon I know this is old, but for people who need the info on "what is a binary/library/configuration?" -- BINARY: Executable file which is ran (e.g. `ls` is a binary as it is compiled code) -- LIBRARY: A dependency which is #include'd (or equivalent) -- CONFIGURATION: Configuration files say "hey do this like this" or "hey do this HERE not HERE" ('configuring' the program)